# PHP & Mysql How to return multiple values from one field

Tags: php, mysql

Please excuse my newbie Question.

I'm tryin to display data from a mysql table into a chart (phpChart http://phpchart.net)
What I need is to display all values of Field cost for Region 'CA'

E.g

```
ID  Cost  Region
----------
1   500    CA
----------
2   100    DP
----------
3   280    CA
----------
4   40     ST
----------
5   80     CA
----------

<?php
include 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT Cost From tblForecast where Region='CA' =";
$rs = mysql_query($query);

if (!$rs) {
    echo "Could not execute query: $query";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
} else {
    echo "Query: $query executed\n";
} 

$nrows = mysql_num_rows($rs);

for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    echo $row[0];
    echo "<br/>";
}

$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array($row[0])),'basic_chart');
\\"This where i'm stuck as to how display the other values within the array"

$pc->set_title(array('text'=>'Basic Chart with Bar Renderer'));
$pc->set_series_default(array('renderer'=>'plugin::BarRenderer'));

$pc->draw();
mysql_close();

?>
```

I'm able to display the first rows value in the chart only.

Anyone's help would be much appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: is your query string wrong?  it looks like an additional quote and equal sign

Comment: what does $nrows return?   1 or.... many?

Comment: Never heard of phpchart.  Looks really useful.

Comment: Yeah thanks i did have a typo there, @CountMurphy they fairly new but look really good and have quite a few features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're continually fetching your query results into a single variable, and overwriting that data on each iteration of the loop.

Try this:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
   $data[] = $row[0];
}

$pc = new C_PhpChartX($data, 'basic_chart');
```

Plus, though this is most likely on a cut/paste type, you've got a syntax error in your query anyways:

```
$query = "SELECT Cost From tblForecast where Region='CA' =";
                                                         ^---syntax error
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work when i use
    `$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array($data[0],$data[1],$data[2])),'basic_chart');`
Is this right, if so how could I do it with out stipulating the array index. i.e show all data

Yes my mistake that was a typo
    `$query = "SELECT Cost From tblForecast where Region='CA' =";`

Comment: just `array($data)`, maybe, if this chart library requires an array-of-arrays.

Comment: Ok, think you might be right this is an example of one of their charts:
    
    
    `$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array(11, 9, 5, 12, 14)),‘basic_chart’);
    $pc->draw();`
    
    
Thanks for the assistance, a step closer in the right direction,

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
include 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Cost) cost
         From tblForecast
         where Region='CA'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo $row['cost']
```